# How to crop to fit to required dimensions without altering image aspect ratio

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have to resize a bunch of images to 1080x864. When downsizing an image the proper resolution is 1080x720 when keeping the aspect ratio.

I am required to use a file size of 1080x864. If I kept the long size of the image at 1080 and resized to retain the aspect ratio, the image would be 1080x720, not 1080x864.

I tried using a program called croptofit and it warps the image. Is there a way to do this? (not keep the aspect ratio but preserve the integrity of the image) Thanks!

Comment: Hi user49073, are you asking how to crop an image in Photoshop or the idea of cropping an image that is not a proper ratio to what you have?

Comment: Who is user talking to??

Comment: @Rafael :)) I thought the same thing. Now that I look closely it's not even a question, it's more like a comment misplaced...

Comment: I think you are lost.

Comment: There is a guy who answered someone else's question who made a program called "croptofit" that works with photoshop. I need to know if it will do what I need. That is, resize an image which should be 1080x720 to 1080x864 without warping the image. If not, I posted another question asking how the heck to do this. Which really is my question - actually I don;t care if I use his program or not, I just am on a deadline and need to do this stupid thing where I resize my images from their normal aspect ratio to the required size without warping the image.

Comment: Photoshop will already let you specify the desired final size. Depending on the image, you can add more canvas and fill it with content aware fill, then crop down from there. Or you can use content aware scaling.

Comment: Hi user49073, I have edited your question to include information from your other posting. Please let me know if the edited question is correct.

Comment: Are you asking how to crop an image to a new aspect ratio without losing any of the original image? If so, that's not possible unless you're willing to live with the distortion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...I hope I understood you correctly...you need to crop images to 1080x864 but they don't have the same aspect ratio? One way of doing this without having white spaces or distorting the image is to create a new document of 1080x864 and place the images in that document and then transform > scale them to fill the canvas.

This would work no matter what aspect ratio your images have :

[image]

> Regarding your comment:

After you've created the new document with the size of 1080x864, you can drag and drop the image, it will look like in img. A below, after you drag the handles (remember to press&hold shift to keep aspect ratio) it will look like img.B...now just press Ctrl+Enter and save it ;).

[image]

Comment: yes, you understand correctly. I have images that are raw but the aspect ratio would be 1080 x 720 or also 1025 x 683. I need to submit them at 1080 x 864, or 1025 x 820. (depending on if they are vertical or horizontal.) This totally warps the image because it does not keep the aspect ratio. By new document, do you mean new canvas size? Also, where is "transform>scale? Finally, it has been a long time since I messed with canvas size and adding images to the canvas; Can you remind me if I just drop and drag the image onto the canvas, or what? Thanks loads! This sounds like the best way for me.

Comment: @user49073 , by new document a literally mean new document, press Ctrl+N and insert the desired height and width (in your case 1080 x 864), then you can drag and drop the images on top of it and once dropped it will take the size of the document (almost) and you will have the scale handles which you can drag to scale (keep Shift pressed while dragging to maintain aspect ratio). Then press Ctrl+Enter to set the image and you can save it with the new dimensions.

Comment: @user49073 If you do it like i said in the comment, you won't need to access the transform by clicking on anything cause when dropping the image it will activate it for you, but for the sake of knowledge, to activate transform manually you need to press Ctrl+T .

Comment: @user49073 , Also, check my update to the answer ;)

Comment: Thank you so much. So I went to file>new, then made a white space 1080x864. Then I opened the image in a separate window, used the move tool, tried to drop and drag to the white space. Did not work. then I made a copy of the background layer, tried to move the layer copy to the white space. This time the image moved within its window, but would not move to the white space. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user49073 My friend, when I say drag and drop, I literally mean drag it from your folder and drop it over the 'white space', no need to open the image in a new window in photoshop. Drag it from your source folder and drop it inside the newly created document aka white space. That is what you were doing wrong.

Comment: oh! Thank you! Can it be a RAW file, or do I need to use a jpg or TIFF? I used to do this drag and drop thing in class all the time for design, but I have been doing photography mainly now for so long I've forgotten how to do everything else in PS. Plus I now have CS6 and everything I learned in the Jurassic age was on way early versions so you never know if something simple has changed.

Comment: AhHA! The problem was I had it in 32 bit. When I deleted the new doc and made another one at 16 bit my image moved over there and I got the lines your image showed in the example. I am now going to proceed and see if I can do the rest. Thank you!!

Comment: Damn. I dragged the handles while holding shift and it did make the image fill the required space but it warped the image anyway. I'll try again  - maybe I didn't hold shift down hard enough?

Comment: My friend, I sure hope you understand that by doing this, a small portion of the image will be lost no matter what...if that is what you mean by wrap. The difference between the two aspect ratios will be reduced from the image itself...there is no way around it. If you want the entire image with no loss but also fit in your required width and height you will need to squeeze, not crop the image. But that never looks good.

Comment: Also, what shift does is lock the aspect ratio while you resize...that is all, it doesn't let the image loose the ratio, if you wanna test the squeeze thingy I mentioned above, you will have to do the same thing except fot the shift.

Comment: PS : Also, while holding Shift make sure to drag the corner handles while if you thy the squeeze effect, drag the middle ones from each side.

Comment: Thank you. What I mean by warp is that it is an image of a bird, and the bird goes from thin to fat. Or in the horizontal case, the bird goes from normal to thin and tall. I don't mind if some of the background is lost. What I mind is the image not staying the same aspect ratio so the actual thing represented looks like it is in a fun house mirror. The average onlooker might not know if they looked at it that an American Kestrel is not that fat, but the people for whom I am doing this do. Also I am not cropping. If normal ratio is 1080x720, making it 1080x864 is enlarging it.

Comment: What you tell me right now is due tothe fact that you are dragging the horizontal or vertical handles, drag only the diagonal ones, say only the top-right corner one while pressing shift, it will enlarge the image proportionally.

Comment: Oh thank you! I think this worked! a Miracle! Thank you! Question: Is it to be expected that when I enlarge them, sometimes if there is not sufficient background around an animal, the enlargement brings a foot or tail to the edge of the image? Because i am enlarging, should I expect the animal will get bigger, though thankfully, proportionately? So I might have to go in to the original raw file and recrop, leaving more room around the animal, so I will have more background to be able to dispense with in the resizing/enlargement? Or does this mean I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @user49073 Well, when you enlarge, everything will be larger so depending on your subject's position in the image you could experience something like what you described but that's due to how the photo has been taken. After you enlarge and hit Ctrl+Enter to fix it, you can press V and use the arrows on your keyboard to move the image up/down/left/right depending on how you enlarged it, in order to avoid things like this. You aren't doing anything wrong :) Best of luck and keep learning. Also, if I answered your question please do mark it as the correct answer :) Good day

Comment: Thank you - you totally answered my question! Thank you for your patience and continuing to work with me until I got it! Now I can do this giant (for me ) project and give the people what they want. Thank you. I clicked the green checkmark - I hope that indicates you answered it.

Comment: @user49073 , Thank you, it does and best of luck !

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 2 options if your required dimension is 1080x864.

1) **Upscale the image** or **Downsize** the height to 864 (not sure if your image is bigger or smaller than required dimensions). This will result in a wider image that you will either have to crop from the left or right or both sides.

2) **Keep width at 1080** and have blank space at the top and bottom of the image (you can then choose what you want as a border color.

For the above methods, you can create this as an action and then use a batch process to do this for multiple images.

Maybe a 3rd option. I am not sure what your end use is but you could keep the width as-is (1080) and export with a transparent background as a PNG.